# Date does not match parsed format in python

Tags: python, datetime

the following snippet of code throws an error stating "ValueError: time data 'Dec 25 2017' does not match format '%b /%d /%y'"

```
import datetime,time
from Hall import Hall

Fd=input("Enter Start time\n")
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(Fd, '%b /%d /%y')

Sd=input("Enter the End time\n")
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(Sd, '%b /%d /%y')

cost=int(input("Enter the cost per day\n"))
x = Hall(d1,d2,cost)
```

The format i want to use is Dec 25 2017. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date that you input, namely `Dec 25 2017`, needs to match the format you specify in `strptime`.

Try the following, and enter the same input `Dec 25 2017`:

```
Fd=input("Enter Start time\n")
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(Fd, '%b %d %Y')

Sd=input("Enter the End time\n")
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(Sd, '%b %d %Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your date format

1. You have some extra `/` that you don't expect
2. And to input the complete year you need to use `%Y` (capital Y)

Try this:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(Sd, '%b %d %Y')
```